# is socketcall() in x86-64 translated to scoket, accept, bind?

Tags: system-calls

On a some architectures—for example, x86-64 and ARM—there is no `socketcall()` system call, instead `socket(2)`, `accept(2)`, `bind(2)`.

If I run a 32-bit program that uses `socketcall()` on a 64-bit system does the system automatically translates `socketcall()` to relevant system call?

Comment: *If I run a 32-bit program that uses `socketcall()`...* Why are you making such a system call directly?  Would you expect a call to `WSAStartup()` to be portable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in what sense would "the system translate"? if there is a syscall for 32-bit binaries, the compat syscall table on the 64-bit system is supposed to provide a matching syscall. internals of that syscall are at the discretion of the implementation, it may be it indeed just straight up ends up calling the other syscalls, or maybe it calls something deeper in the kernel. or maybe it is exactly the same as it is in the native 32-bit kernel.

figuring out how it exactly looks like is left as an exercise for the reader